# stackoverflow.com JavaScript Disabled Banner?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, javascript

I'm having trouble getting all of the features to work on stackoverflow.com. When I visit the site it displays a banner which says, "Stack Overflow works best with JavaScript enabled." However I have javascript enabled and other websites seem to work fine. I am running Mac OS X 10.6.6 and I've tested with Chrome, Firefox, and Safari. I get the error in all three browsers.

I have reinstalled Adobe Flash Player and Chrome in an attempt to see if that would help. It didn't seem to solve anything tho :/

Has anyone else experienced this issue?

Comment: This happened to me, tonight. I *think*, in my case, it was due to other services running and taking bandwidth, though. But +1 for the repro.

Answer (score 5):

For some time, that warning also popped up when jQuery wasn't available. (On March 3rd, that was a recent change, before that it would just fail silently.) Since about March 28, it specifically warns:

> Stack Overflow works best with jQuery enabled

Do you have googleapis.com blocked?

Comment: Given [buti-oxa's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81546/stackoverflow-com-javascript-disabled-banner/82247#82247) and the availability of IE9: any chance the jQuery error message could be made more specific? (See also [Can't ask a question when IE Tracking Protection is enabled](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80044/cant-ask-a-question-when-ie-tracking-protection-is-enabled).)

Comment: And for [some](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84979/stackoverflow-bug-in-firefox-4-0-javascript-not-working-even-if-its-enabled) an old version of AdBlock blocked the loading of jQuery (probably blocked access to Google's CDN) in Firefox 4. I really think making the message a bit more specific might help! Or, SHAME ON YOU GUYS: the sites just work TOO WELL without jQuery, leaving folks wondering what is causing the message while all seems to work just fine. ;-)

Comment: @Arjan: I've changed the message to say "jQuery" instead of "JavaScript". I've resisted the temptation to change the message to "-1 not enough jQuery" :)

Comment: I wonder if a similar check should be added to the HTML itself (or hosted from `/content/js/`), for SE's own script? For a browser, `googleapis.com` and `sstatic.net` are both third party domains, but if the latter is blocked, the warning function won't even run of course. (I'm really scared of IE9's blocking mechanism, if that is really silently blocking things which it erroneously thinks are ads. I cannot test IE9 though; maybe it's not that bad at all.)

Comment: (Ah, @balpha, my last comment is also an old feature request, though not very well worded I guess: [Notify to enable JavaScript on sstatic.net](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14779/notify-to-enable-javascript-on-sstatic-net).)

Comment: Just stalking you a bit: if you could come up with detecting if `sstatic.net` is blocked, [then some](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88769/parts-of-ui-suddenly-dont-work-anymore-in-firefox-work-in-ie) will be happy ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Another possible reason: IE with InPrivate Filtering enabled. Once it notices that jQuery is linked from Google by many web-pages you use, it decides it's an ad and blocks it.

Comment: Good old IE fannying everything up again

Comment: At least they got one thing right in IE!

Comment: @Gabe, how is the behavior described in the above answer the right thing to do? One day a site works just fine, the next day IE decides to block something?

Answer (score 2):

Is some sort of a firewall blocking `.js` URLs on your infrastructure?

See if you can open the below URL in a browser.

http://sstatic.net/js/master.min.js?v=3850e24bc920

Comment: Is it supposed to be a whole bunch of code? Because that is what I see.

Comment: @YGomez: Yes, it was the minified JavaScript code as of March 3rd 2011.

Answer (score 0):

see this link ["Stack Overflow works best with JavaScript enabled", but I have JavaScript enabled by default](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/72020/154511)