# External JavaScript error text should include the failing domain

Tags: feature-request

Visiting StackOverflow with partial external request blocking results in a red error banner across the top of the page with text like this:

> Meta Stack Overflow requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load.

I expect to see:

> Meta Stack Overflow requires external JavaScript from www.foobar.com, which is blocked or failed to load.

The original message brings back the frustration of "An error occurred. [OK] [Cancel]" If I know which domain is the culprit, I might be able to fix it; knowing that some domain on the Internet is the problem? No hope there, no domain to whitelist, nada.

With the domain, I can consider whether I want to unblock it, and do so. If it's warning about a domain I don't care about, I can probably rig up a way to hide the error message on my end, or just suck it up and know that it's Chicken Littling. As it stands, it's either allow all requests or none, and I'm not - and some users on some networks might not have the option of - doing the former.

Comment: I *think* it only [checks for jQuery Mobile](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89433/stack-overflow-requires-external-javascript-from-another-domain-message/89460#89460), and only if downloading the scripts from `sstatic.net` is successful first. (While there are [some other domains](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need/71208#71208) that help making it the best experience.) Related: [Notify to enable JavaScript on sstatic.net](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14779/notify-to-enable-javascript-on-sstatic-net).

Comment: And some more history in [How do I enable jQuery?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89709/how-do-i-enable-jquery), in which balpha also writes: We're *not* going to add the same for sstatic, because that would mean serving extra stuff *for every request in the network*, and if sstatic.net JavaScript is not available, the chances are about 100% that this is the result of a *conscious* NoScript blocking (because if this was due to e.g. network issues, the CSS files would be gone as well, which makes it pretty easy to notice something's wrong).